# How to get last record based on a date with some other aggregate column in a SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I know this question is already asked like 100 time and I reviewed all of them but I'm Kinda Stuck and had to asked for help

I have table like this:

```
hivenumber Visitdate   CombsNO  WaxNo  BeeBehave
------------------------------------------------
    1      2017-11-10    10       2        4
    2      2017-11-10    11       1        3
    3      2017-11-10    12       3        3
    1      2017-11-12    13       1        1
    3      2017-11-11    14       5        2
```

At first I want to aggregate it by `HiveNumber`

```
Select HiveNumber 
From tHivesDetails
Group BY HiveNumber
```

Then I want the last record of `CombNo` for each `HiveNumber`

```
Select Top(1) CombNo 
From `tHivesDetails` 
Order By VisitDate Desc
```

Then I need sum of `Wax` for each `HiveNumber`

```
Select Sum(Wax) 
From `tHivesDetails` 
Group BY HiveNumber
```

and at the end I want average of `BeeBehave`

```
Select Avg(BeeBehave) 
From tHivesDetails
Group By HiveNumber
```

I don't know how to combine these queries to 1 and have one table with all I need in this case. I read most of same question but unfortunately couldn't figure it how do that.

I want a result like this:

```
hivenumber  Visitdate  CombsNO  WaxNo  BeeBehave
------------------------------------------------
    1      2017-11-12    13      Sum      avg
    2      2017-11-10    11      sum      avg
    3      2017-11-11    14      sum      avg
```

Comment: @PatJones Yes My Problem is with the second one
I will edit my question to show an example right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Window Functions" to the rescue. You can use aggregate functions with an `over clause` to produce values **on each row** of a result. `ROW_NUMBER()` allows use of order by as well, do by ordering within each "partition" by the dates descending, the number 1 is given to "the most recent:" visit (per hive due to the partition).

```
select *
from (
       Select *
         , row_number() over(partition by HiveNumber order by VisitDate DESC) rn
         , sum(Wax) over(partition by HiveNumber) sum_wax
         , Avg(BeeBehave) over(partition by HiveNumber) avg_bb
       From tHivesDetails
      ) d
where rn = 1
```

Comment: tanks alot I've wrote a 100o queries and all of them failed but this seems to work and also tanks for explanation
i will accept the answer asap

Comment: I have question
in with part query get last record for `CombsNo`?
I mean if I want to have another column to get last record of it how should I add it to the query?

Comment: this is like get every last record for each aggregated HiveNumber. right?

Comment: if you mean can I add extra columns into the `order by` that affects how row_number() assigns numbers, then sure, of course you can. If you mean something else then you need to explain more.

Comment: I mean if I had another column next to ComsNo like `eggNo` how can I get last record of that column like CombNo, but seem that this query get last record for all off other columns of my table (that is exactly what I need)

Comment: 'partition by' is similar to 'group by' except it does not collapse the number of rows. `order by` works **within** EACH partition. So if you partition by Hive, and order by visit date DESC, you get "the most recent visit"  for each Hive. I do not know how to make this clearer, I suggest you try it. And while trying it, reverse the oder of dates from DESC to ASC (then you get "the oldest visit" instead). *It will become clear once you play with it. oh, nclude rn in the result so you can see it and remove "rn = 1"*

Comment: it is a matter of trying it. you have both `partition by` and `order by` as options. try them

Comment: tanks for gooood goood explantation, fully understood :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT tA.HiveNumber, tA.WaxNoSum, tA.BeeBehaveSum, tB.CombsNoLatest
FROM (SELECT HiveNumber, SUM(WaxNo) AS WaxNoSum, AVG(BeeBehave) AS BeeBehaveSum  
      FROM tHivesDetails
      GROUP BY HiveNumber) AS tA LEFT JOIN (SELECT HiveNumber, MAX(CombsNO) AS CombsNoLatest
                                            FROM tHivesDetails
                                            GROUP BY HiveNumber) AS tB ON tA.HiveNumber = tB.HiveNumber
```

Comment: tanks it works but I get Null for CombsNo if there wasn't any record for i at last date of other record

Comment: Actually I wrote my second sub-query incorrectly. Writing it using a GROUP BY and MAX on the CombsNo column ensures a number for every row. Answer updated.